# NodeJS/NestJS - Serving HTTP requests asynchronously

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I'm working on NestJS REST API. The requirement is reply immediately to the client and do the processing in the background. The reason is that the background process is time consuming and don't want the client to wait for the reply.

I saw Python has Uvicorn library which helps to achieve this. Is it possible to do in NestJS?

Comment: APIs often **require** a return value. Take GET requests that return data. How are these supposed to run in an async way where a reply is immediately sent to the client and then the processing is done and then yet another reply is supposed to be returned? Are you going to never return anything to the client or what? On the other hand, the server async processing is not about replying early but about releasing the listener while it performs an internal async task (like writing to a file) so that it can handle another request in the meantime. Aren't you confusing the two forms of asynchronicity?

Comment: My bad, I didn't put it in a correct words. You are right, for GET calls, the client will wait for the response. However, for POST calls, client will get the acknowledged response (HTTP 200) and the server will do the processing in the background.

Comment: While you could theoretically execute promises without waiting (no `await`, no `then`) (so called *fire and forget*), it's risky as it means that errors are possibly not handled. A more mature option would be to have a messaging middleware (e.g. RabbitMQ) where such async tasks are put and then picked up by a bunch of workers and processed independently.